# Android: Does Tablets support telephony?

Tags: android

I just came to know to restrict my app only to be downloaded on Phones but not on Tablets I have to enforce the telephony feature into my Manifest file by adding

```
<uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.telephony"></uses-feature>
```

Now my questions does the tablets support telephony, Can I make regular calls from tablets. I just came across some posts which says it is possible. If yes the how to restrict the app to get downloaded only on phones not tablets. I am bit confused. Could anybody have the genuine answer for this.

I also read the following post on Android FAQs

> **What kinds of devices can be Android
> compatible?**
>
> The Android software can
> be ported to a lot of different kinds
> of devices, including some on which
> third-party apps won't run properly.
> The Android Compatibility Definition
> Document (CDD) spells out the specific
> device configurations that will be
> considered compatible.
>
> For example, though the Android source
> code could be ported to run on a phone
> that doesn't have a camera, the CDD
> requires that in order to be
> compatible, all phones must have a
> camera. This allows developers to rely
> on a consistent set of capabilities
> when writing their apps.
>
> The CDD will evolve over time to
> reflect market realities. For
> instance, the 1.6 CDD only allows cell
> phones, but the 2.1 CDD allows devices
> to omit telephony hardware, allowing
> for non-phone devices such as
> tablet-style music players to be
> compatible. As we make these changes,
> we will also augment Android Market to
> allow developers to retain control
> over where their apps are available.
> To continue the telephony example, an
> app that manages SMS text messages
> would not be useful on a media player,
> so Android Market allows the developer
> to restrict that app exclusively to
> phone devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all tablets support telephony, but some do.

Actually telephony is an "umbrella feature", where the tablet may support some sub-features.

There is a an explanation on [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/best-practices-for-honeycomb-and.html) and links for further information.

Comment: Thanks Heiko, Is there any strict way to exclude the tablets for my app??

Comment: These days I'd say huge screens

Comment: You mean to say if I specify <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false"/>, my app will be restricted to Phones???

Comment: Yes - at least for now this should work. Why do you want to restrict yourself?

Comment: Heiko, if I specify <support-screens> into the Manifest file, it limits the application's screen to the specified sizes and draws a black background around the application, the app will still can be downloaded.

Comment: Sorry, then I am out of ideas.

Comment: Then will the app crash on a tablet if I am using this permission? `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: I have this question regarding it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193753/can-tablets-make-calls-telephony

Comment: Feel free to answer it :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a PC windows tablet, you can use USB telephony device or so called usb voice modem to create a full featured telephony solutions. Since it uses usb to connect to your tablet and resolve the hardware layer issues.